# how can I create a dynamic video file?

Tags: java, video, dynamic, video-processing

I want to create a video file with dynamic content.

specifically,I want to:
- read a number from an extrnal text file
- show the number in the video
- add voice announcing the number

I want this file to be updated once an hour,so the number will be different each time the file is created.

any programming language or video editor is ok.
Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can give a try with [JMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework)